# Entity update using hibernate second level cache

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, caching, second-level-cache

To reduce database load I want to move hot entities to hibernate second level cache.

Frequency of reads and updates in the application is approximately equal and single entity gets updated many times a second.

From analyzing hibernate logs and second level cache statistics, I see that "selects" are executed from the cache, and "updates" are propagated to database.

Is it possible to update entities only in cache and flush the cache once in a while? If the cache collapses, the application can restore the lost updates.

Comment: If an entity is updated that often, I have doubts second level cache will be of a lot of use since there's work required to keep the cache in synch with the database. You can just disable second level cache for this particular entity and leave it for the others which are not updated that often. Did you try that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** after researching all kinds of solutions the conclusion is that **hibernate second level cache is not a suitable choice** when there are many updates that should be committed to cache only.

But there is still a transparent solution. Hibernate interceptors and event listeners allow a relatively simple proprietary cache handling. We use Hazelcast as cache provider that supports distributed Map, transactions, locking, pub/sub.